# Will a return inside of a for loop leak memory?

Tags: c#, for-loop, memory-leaks, return

Basically all I need to know is whether or not a return inside of a for loop will cause a memory leak in c#.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++ ) {
    if(i == 10)
        return;
}
```

Normally I would not write code like this but I was wondering what would happen if I did.

Comment: Just curious: what *would* there be to "leak"?

Comment: If you explain your thinking about why this might leak memory, someone can probably give you some insight.  Otherwise, all we can say is 'no'.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe Ephyxia is wondering whether or not the loop continues to iterate after the `return` executes.

Comment: This would not leak memory in any language that I'm aware of, even C++. You should probably spend some time reading about memory leaks and how they happen. Specifically, you have to *allocate* memory, and then lose your reference to it, to leak memory. This is not the same as declaring a local variable and then returning. This may assist you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap-based_memory_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation

Comment: Also interesting why "Normally I would not write code like this" - can you explain what is wrong with return/break from the loop? I can't imagine how one would write "find element" without such return/break and avoid uselessly checking each item...

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would be like having a goto to jump loop, I know in some other languages this will cause memory leaks or a stack overflow because it will store the address of the beginning of the loop and when it gets to the end (the '}' in this case) it jumps back to the stored address, if it never finds the 'end' of the loop that address stays in memory. I wasn't sure if c# handled this automatically or not

Comment: Your concern doesn't even make sense. I can't think of any other language where it would cause any kind of problem to return from inside a loop. It's a very common programming technique.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is one variable in scope here, `i`. As this would seem to be part of a method, and therefore allocated on the stack, so when the method returns, the memory is reclaimed. As only a single integer value is involved, I suspect you can cope without that space between the for loop ending and the method exiting.

Answer (score 0):

This will not cause any memory leaks because when you `return` from any loop or method, it ends the process and "returns" out of it.   `break;` works the same way.

The only way you would possibly have a data leak is if you were dealing with pointers, and you left the loop without destucting them.